# Access github username in Azure Devops predefined variables

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

I have been reading this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml to find out which user from Github triggered the build. (There is a build for every commit)
I tried using `Build.RequestedFor`  but it outputs `Github`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access github username in Azure Devops predefined variables

I suppose the user from Github triggered the build is not the owner or admin of the Github repo.

As test, I submit the change to the github repo with different accounts, one is the `owner`/`Admin`, another is a `collaborator`. I could get the user name and e-mail for the account `owner`/`Admin` by the predefined variables `Build.RequestedFor` and `Build.RequestedForEmail`:

[image]

But, if I use the `collaborator` account, I could could not find out those two values:

[image]

I think this is by designed to protect user information, otherwise, we could get other user's `usernames` and `emails` through a github connection service. Obviously this is not secure. This should also be the reason why the value you get is `github`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I thought but this section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-are-the-identity-variables-set) says that the variable `Build.RequestedFor` should be 'The person who pushed or checked in the changes.'